# How do I get the size of a MySQL table row in megabytes?

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to get the size of a table but how can I query the size of an individual table row in megabytes?

The post [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?501755-PHP-get-row-size-%28bytes%29-from-MySQL) suggests:

```
$rowLength = 0; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'"); 

if(!$result) { 
    die('Could not run query'); 
}    

$lengths = mysql_fetch_lengths($result); 

foreach($lengths as $length) { 
    $rowLength += $length; 
}    

echo "\$rowLength = $rowLength";
```

... but the solution appears to accumulate field length values, where I need the byte size (converted to Mb).

Comment: Simple, if you can get the size of table, then you can get row count in table and calculate row size: row size = table size / row count :)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: that would be the *average* size of an row, not the size of a specific row.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - sorry an average will not work, as I'll need to know the specific row size.

Comment: Why do you even need to know this? Do you actually have a business case where this information is necessary?

Comment: @Inator - but clearly it's some kind of business secret that you can't share

Comment: @Mark - No secret per se... I'm developing a SAAS platform that includes a limit on the amount of DB storage depending on the plan they choose.  I'd like to be able to report down to the record level on usage if possible.  Each record will contain at least one medium-text field, so there will be significant variance from one record to the next.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a row depends on the engine used, I don't think there's a golden rule.

For instance with *InnoDB*, you can use the following specs to determine the size of a row: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-physical-record.html . If you use *MyISAM*, you should follow: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-table-formats.html .

Comment: Helpful, but I need to know the row size with data, not just the size based on the configuration of the fields.